# Parrot OS Installation Failed

Tags: linux, persistence, partition, parrot-os

So I booted Parrot OS from an external drive (SanDisk 3.2Gen1) and I gave it 32GB of persistence (I don't know if it really does anything to help). Now I am trying to partition the drive. Everything goes well untill i try to install it to the drive. It just pops this error and I don't know what to do next.
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFnNz.jpg)

I have tried to do it with the GParted program but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to partition the drive the live system runs on?
If so, try booting from another drive than the one you'd like to partition.